# Default error function for jQuery promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

Is there a way to set up a default error function for a jQuery promise?

I have a chain of functions to execute asynchronously, and if any of them fails, I want to report the error. Here's what I have to do now:

```
function myErrorFunc() {
  // report error
}

doSomething.then(doSomething2(), myErrorFunc).then(doSomething3(), myErrorFunc).then( ... )
```

I'd prefer to set the default error function some place and then just call

```
doSomething.then(doSomething2()).then(doSomething3()).then( ... );
```

Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I accepted someone else's answer, I found a better one:

```
function myWrapperFunction() {
    return doSomething().fail(myErrorFunction());
}
```

Now all I have to do is call `myWrapperFunction().then()` and the error function is in place.

Comment: Note that this will execute the caller's callback even on error, which you probably don't want.

Comment: `myErrorFunction()` you just called the handler _immediately_.

Answer (score 2):

Errors propagate through a promise chain.

You can simply write

```
promise.then(a).then(b).then(c).then(null, onError)
```

Answer (score -1):

update the default error function with a custom prototype

```
function NewError(message) {
  this.name = "NewError";
this.message = (message || "");
}
 NewError.prototype = Error.prototype;
```

Comment: That is not at all what he's asking for.